# What is the " Unit " of time returned by psutil.cpu_times()?

Tags: python, linux, centos, psutil, cpu-time

Is it seconds? I am trying to match it with the output of `top -n 1 | grep Cpu` command, and they look different!

```
>>> psutil.cpu_times()
scputimes(user=678.99, nice=2.15, system=405.34, idle=414554.14, iowait=12.95, irq=0.0, softirq=2.43, steal=95.2, guest=0.0, guest_nice=0.0)
>>> exit()
[root@Server]# top -n 1 | grep Cpu
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's seconds. The reference docs for this are here:

https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.cpu_times

> Every attribute represents the seconds the CPU has spent in the given mode.

For a description of the `top` is giving you, refer to this answer:

https://superuser.com/questions/575202/understanding-top-command-in-unix

The values you're seeing from `top` are percentages, hence they don't align with the values you're seeing from `psutil`

To be honest, it's not clear what you're trying to achieve here.